# Whether a Locker should be used when an Isolate is created and executed on different threads？

Tags: v8

I'm embedding the V8 into my project, I create a pool of Isolates on one thread, and other worker thread fetch Isolates from the pool, and each isolate will belong to exactly one thread until the owner puts it back. As a result, the creation and execution of an isolate happen on different threads, whether I should use a Locker before entering the isolate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that only one thread at a time uses a given Isolate. You don't need to use `v8::Locker` for that, you can also use your own mechanism.

Whether you "should" use `v8::Locker` probably comes down to personal preference ☺